# Shell scripting using grep to split a string

Tags: regex, string, shell, scripting, grep

I have a variable in my shell script of the form

```
myVAR = "firstWord###secondWord"
```

I would like to use grep or some other tool to separate into two variables such that the final result is:

```
myFIRST = "firstWord"
mySECOND = "secondWord"
```

How can I go about doing this? #{3} is what I want to split on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using substitution with `sed`:

```
echo $myVAR | sed -E  's/(.*)#{3}(.*)/\1/'
>>> firstword

echo $myVAR | sed -E  's/(.*)#{3}(.*)/\2/'
>>> secondword

# saving to variables
myFIRST=$(echo $myVAR | sed -E  's/(.*)#{3}(.*)/\1/')

mySECOND=$(echo $myVAR | sed -E  's/(.*)#{3}(.*)/\2/')
```

Comment: Hey I don't have the -E option working on my machine, and I don't see it on the man page

Comment: It's an alias for `-r` which is extended regex, I guess you are using linux then... `-E` is more portable (supported on Mac ect where `-r` isn't). My preference is `-r` but always use `-E` when answering question if the platform is unknown... It's always confused my why the man pages don't say it's supported.

Comment: Ok well that's cool I like your solution and it works with -r for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The best tool for this is [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ echo "firstWord###secondWord" | sed 's@###@\
@'
firstWord
secondWord
```

A complete example :

```
$ read myFIRST mySECOND < <(echo "$myvar" | sed 's@###@ @')

$ echo $myFIRST 
firstWord

$ echo $mySECOND 
secondWord
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ STR='firstWord###secondWord'
$ eval $(echo $STR | sed 's:^:V1=":; /###/ s::";V2=": ;s:$:":')
$ echo $V1
firstWord
$ echo $V2
secondWord
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it with zsh:

```
myVAR="firstWord###secondWord"
<<<$myvar sed 's/###/ /' | read myFIRST mySECOND
```